# Can not access network share of windows 7 from ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba

I have a problem in ubuntu 12.04

My lan settings are as follows:

4 windows pc.
1 ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

I can see all the network pc on my ubuntu network.

I can access shared folders of 3 windows PC but can not access folders of 1 windows PC.

[image]

Can anybody tell me what should be the problem??

Comment: did you install samba?

Comment: Yes i installed samba

Comment: I can access other windows pc but can not access only single windows pc.

Answer (score 0):

You must not had shared your directory or given permissions to the windows folder.

Check the network sharing and enable the network sharing.

Comment: The shared folder can be seen on all other pc but can not access only in ubuntu pc.

Comment: can you see other pcs?

Comment: Yes i can see other pcs.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118634/cant-access-windows-7-shared-files-on-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue.. check connection type, public/work/home and verify folders are being shared via network sharing center by enabling file sharing

Also its a good idea to not allow everyone, and specify a user with a decent password. Then book mark it from your Linux device after.

Basically How I run my media server.

Comment: The password protection is only useful if you must allow untrusted devices on your local network. Otherwise it's security theatre.

Comment: You should always protect your devices. Its not too difficult to gain access to a network. Sitting in a car snoopin on wireless is fairly easy to break peoples wifi passwords. Its best to have several levels of security to protect your computer/data from being compromised.

Comment: Breaking into WPA2 networks isn't easy, if their key is derived from a password with sufficient entropy.

Comment: how many people make passwords that are sufficient that aren't in IT? 123456 is still a very popular password... don’t even need to crack the encryption, a dictionary attack is right around the corner and faster..

jus sayin

ALSO.. how hard is it to hack a windows machine that is trusted on a network? As much as i hate to admit that i own computers with windows on it...